# Morris.js Donut Label not in center jquery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

I have a new problem with Morris.js.  I am currently using the redraw function to redraw the graph on tab click in order for it to display correctly.  The problem is that when doing this with the donut graphs, when the graph is redrawn, the centre label position is miscalculated.  Once on the tab if you hover over a section it works fine again.  If you leave the tab and come back it's fine.  It is just the first time the centre text loads.  I assume the redraw() in morris is not covering the text.  Not sure how to tackle this one.

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d1owfmoc/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs2">
<div id="tabs-1" class="statdiv">
        <h4>Tab 1</h4>

    <div class="statgrid">
        <div class="col-2-6">
            <div id="morris-donut-chart"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="statgrid">
        <div class="col-4-6">
            <div class="col-5-6">Item 1</div>
            <div class="col-1-6">&pound;10.00</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2" class="statdiv">
        <h4>Tab 2</h4>

    <div class="statgrid">
        <div class="col-2-6">
            <div id="morris-donut-chart2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="statgrid">
        <div class="col-4-6">
            <div class="col-5-6">Item 2</div>
            <div class="col-1-6">&pound;10.00</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3" class="statdiv">
        <h4>Tab 3</h4>

    <div class="statgrid">
        <div class="col-2-6">
            <div id="morris-donut-chart3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="statgrid">
        <div class="col-4-6">
            <div class="col-5-6">Item 3</div>
            <div class="col-1-6">&pound;10.00</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="tabs-4" class="statdiv">
        <h4>Tab 4</h4>

    <div class="statgrid">
        <div class="col-2-6">
            <div id="morris-donut-chart4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="statgrid">
        <div class="col-4-6">
            <div class="col-5-6">Item 4</div>
            <div class="col-1-6">&pound;10.00</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="tabcontain3">
    <ul class="mytabs2">
        <li class="stattab1"><a href="#tabs-1" data-toggle="tab" data-identifier="donut1">Tab 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="stattab2"><a href="#tabs-2" data-toggle="tab" data-identifier="donut2">Tab 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="stattab3"><a href="#tabs-3" data-toggle="tab" data-identifier="donut3">Tab 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="stattab4"><a href="#tabs-4" data-toggle="tab" data-identifier="donut4">Tab 4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
  $("#tabs2").tabs();
});

$('ul.mytabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  var types = $(this).attr("data-identifier");
  var typesArray = types.split(",");
  $.each(typesArray, function (key, value) {
      eval(value + ".redraw()");
  })
});

$(function () {

  var donut1_data = [{

      label: "Download Sales",
      value: 12
  }, {
      label: "In-Store Sales",
      value: 30
  }, {
      label: "Mail-Order Sales",
      value: 20
  }];

  var donut1 = {
      element: 'morris-donut-chart',
      data: donut1_data,
      resize: false
  }

  donut1 = Morris.Donut(donut1)



  var donut2_data = [{

      label: "Download Sales",
      value: 10
  }, {
      label: "In-Store Sales",
      value: 30
  }, {
      label: "Mail-Order Sales",
      value: 20
  }];

  var donut2 = {
      element: 'morris-donut-chart2',
      data: donut2_data,
      resize: false
  }

  donut2 = Morris.Donut(donut2)



  var donut3_data = [{

      label: "Download Sales",
      value: 8
  }, {
      label: "In-Store Sales",
      value: 30
  }, {
      label: "Mail-Order Sales",
      value: 20
  }];

  var donut3 = {
      element: 'morris-donut-chart3',
      data: donut3_data,
      resize: false
  }

  donut3 = Morris.Donut(donut3)


  var donut4_data = [{

      label: "Download Sales",
      value: 2
  }, {
      label: "In-Store Sales",
      value: 30
  }, {
      label: "Mail-Order Sales",
      value: 20
  }];

  var donut4 = {
      element: 'morris-donut-chart4',
      data: donut4_data,
      resize: false
  }

  donut4 = Morris.Donut(donut4)



});
```

CSS:

```
#morris-donut-chart svg, #morris-donut-chart2 svg, #morris-donut-chart3 svg, #morris-donut-chart4 svg {
width:250px;
height:250px;
}
#morris-donut-chart, #morris-donut-chart2, #morris-donut-chart3, #morris-donut-chart4 {
width:250px;
height:250px;
}
```

Comment: Use `$('ul.mytabs2 a').on('click', function (e) {` instead of `$('ul.mytabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {`, you dont have `mytabs` and what is `shown.bs.tab`. Change them and you have errors in console: `donut2 is not defined`

Comment: Thanks for spotting that.  I have updated to mytabs2 and tried the click function instead and still no joy on redraw.  Will have a look at errors shortly need to fly out.  But don't believe that is the cause of the issue I am trying to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should replace `mytabs` with `mytabs2` in your jquery code because you dont have a `mytabs` class.

After that change `shown.bs.tab` to `click` because you want to redraw the donut when a tab is `clicked`.

And at last, move your `click` function into the `$(function ()` because the variables `donut1`,`donut2`, etc are not accessible outside `function()`:

```
$(function () {
    $('ul.mytabs2 a').on('click', function (e) {
      var types = $(this).attr("data-identifier");
      var typesArray = types.split(",");
      $.each(typesArray, function (key, value) {
          eval(value + ".redraw()");
      })
    });
});
```

Here's the working example: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d1owfmoc/2/)

Comment: Thanks Raeen. Demo looks great. Just had to nip out. Will accept and up once I get back.